# php static function

Tags: php, class, static, member

I have a question regarding static function in php.

let's assume that I have a class

```
class test {
    public function sayHi() {
        echo 'hi';
    }
}
```

if I do `test::sayHi();` it works without a problem.

```
class test {
    public static function sayHi() {
        echo 'hi';
    }
}
```

`test::sayHi();` works as well.

What are the differences between first class and second class?

What is special about a static function?

Comment: As of php7 you cannot call non static method statically

Answer (score 157, accepted):

In the first class, `sayHi()` is actually an instance method which you are calling as a static method and you get away with it because `sayHi()` never refers to `$this`.

Static functions are associated with the class, not an instance of the class. As such, `$this` is not available from a static context (`$this` isn't pointing to any object).

Comment: Now static calling of non-static methods works but is deprecated. Be careful using this syntax for instance methods!

Comment: So this why they say it as static function? because there is no multiple instance with dynamic data flow and dynamic output. Just guide me.@chaos

Answer (score 22):

Simply, static functions function independently of the class where they belong.

$this means, this is an object of this class.  It does not apply to static functions.

```
class test {
    public function sayHi($hi = "Hi") {
        $this->hi = $hi;
        return $this->hi;
    }
}
class test1 {
    public static function sayHi($hi) {
        $hi = "Hi";
        return $hi;
    }
}

//  Test
$mytest = new test();
print $mytest->sayHi('hello');  // returns 'hello'
print test1::sayHi('hello');    //  returns 'Hi'
```

Comment: Ok I'm not a PHP wizard, but isn't the variable ('hello') that is passed to the static function, explicitly being overwritten with 'Hi'? Meaning that the line print test1::sayHi('hello'); would not return 'hello', but would return 'hi'?

Comment: This answer is sloppy (the effect of static functions *can* depend on which class they're in) and the examples don't make the point very clear.

Comment: Not a very good example. $hi = 'Hi'; overwrites the given argument, and has nothing to do with static declaration. I would fix this like: self::$hi = $hi; and it would work just like the non-static one. You can access the class variables with self:: instead of $this->

Answer (score 20):

Entire difference is, you don't get `$this` supplied inside the static function.  If you try to use `$this`, you'll get a `Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context`.

Well, okay, one other difference: an `E_STRICT` warning is generated by your first example.

Comment: i have no warning when i use first and i'm in php7

Comment: Why don't we have $this inside a static function? What's the architectural logic of this? Thanks.

Comment: @LucasBustamante: `$this` refers to the current object.  In a static function, there is no current object; the function exists on the class without need for or reference to an object instance of that class.

Answer (score 4):

Calling non-static methods statically generates an E_STRICT level warning.

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell, you don't have the object as $this in the second case, as 
the static method is a function/method of the class not the object instance.

Comment: is static simply how you define class functions? no other fancy business? So you're saying if it had been called "class_method" rather than "static", it would be more semantic?

Answer (score 1):

After trying examples (PHP 5.3.5), I found that in both cases of defining functions you can't use `$this` operator to work on class functions. So I couldn't find a difference in them yet. :(