# php class methods used statically without class reference?

Tags: php, class, static

I have a class like this:

```
class Utils{

   public function hello()
   {
      return "<b>Hello World</b></br>";
   }

}
```

Can I now do something directly like this in my `page.php`:

require_once("classes/Utils.php");

`echo hello();`

Or must I do this:

```
$u = new Utils;
$u->hello();
```

even though the function contains no object properties that need to be instantiated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you declare your function as static.

```
class Utils{

   public static function hello()
   {
      return "<b>Hello World</b></br>";
   }

}
```

and call it as

```
Utils::hello()
```

[php static function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902909/php-static-function)

Comment: but is the `Utils::` necessary as a prefix, rather than just `hello()`? Assuming there's no other class required in the file that also has a `hello()` method.

Comment: Yes, that's what indicates a static function call. If you just write hello() you are calling a global function not from a class.

Answer (score 0):

actually you call static methods like this:

```
Utils::hello();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call it directly like:

```
echo Utils::hello();
```

Here is a [PHPFiddle example](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/n1v-bx3)